# Jest (JS) segmentation fault 11 in IO.js 1.4.3 when using require()

Tags: node.js, testing, segmentation-fault, jestjs, io.js

I'm using IO.js 1.4.3 and Jest to run my test suites. I need a newer version of V8 because I am using ES6 features like Promises.

If I try the simplest possible test:

```
describe('the truth', function() {
    it('is true', function() {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

it works (thankfully). If I include, however, a call to `require()` (which I have to do to test my own code), I get:

```
Using Jest CLI v0.4.0
Waiting on 1 test...Segmentation fault: 11
```

This happens irrespective of which module I include, and whether I make a call to `jest.dontMock()` first.

This doesn't really tell me very much qua error message, and `require` really does seem to be the problem. Are there any solutions to this other than reverting to pre-1.0 node.js?

Comment: Can you make an example git repo to demonstrate the bug? `Segmentation fault` errors are tough to track down, especially since this could be happening for several reasons.

Comment: I've discovered that this error seems to be directly related to using a higher node version. Rolling back to v0.10.38 makes Jest work, but I don't really know why that is.

Answer (score 2):

This happens in cases where you have installed `node_modules` using `node` at some version, and then later switching to `iojs` using `nvm install iojs` and trying to run the installed `node_modules` with `npm`. It isn't likely that this is your issue, but hopefully anyone else googling around can try this and fix it.

```
nvm install iojs
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

then running whatever it is you're trying to run, usually something like `npm run start`.

Comment: You're right that this wasn't my issue, I'd already tried rebuilding my node modules. Luckily it's been fixed in some of the Jest deps.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults almost always come from native C++ code, since JS cannot cause such crashes unless it triggers a V8 bug. As such, I'd suspect the issue is with the contextify native module that jest indirectly depends on (via jsdom).

It might be worth trying to hack together a version of jest that depends on the latest jsdom, which no longer has a native module dependency.

Comment: It started working with later versions of IO.js. There's some discussion in various Jest issues on this but it seems largely unresolved.